# Apply resize on multiple images at one time in openCV python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have read a folder containing pictures using glob and imread. Now my I want to resize all of those pictures using for loop in cv2.resize.

following is my code but the output is not correct--

```
import cv2
import glob



path = glob.glob("C:/Users/RX-91-9/Desktop/prescriptions/*.jpg")
for file in (path):
img=cv2.imread(file)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.cv2.waitKey(3)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

for i in img:
resized_image = cv2.resize(i, (1600,1600)) 
cv2.imshow('resized_image', resized_image)
cv2.waitKey(3)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I don't know why the last for loop is not giving the expected output, i want all the images in 'img' to be resized. Please help if you find what is wrong in my for last for loop.

Comment: What are you getting as output? Could you elaborate on *not correct*?

Comment: i am getting infinite blank images in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have a list of images in some folder and you to resize all of them. You can run

```
import cv2
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('images/*.jpg'): # path to your images folder
    print(filename)
    img=cv2.imread(filename) 
    rl=cv2.resize(img, (500,500))
    cv2.imwrite(f'{filename}resized.jpg', rl)
```

Comment: what if i want to apply grayscale , threshholding and dilation in these images further because i want to extracy text from them using tesseract.

Comment: Google it out. You will find many solutions

Comment: what if I have some png images also in that folder, can i add those also with the jpg simultaneously?